# Closed-form expression for power of a matrix by Fibonacci number

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, fibonacci-numbers

Suppose that $f_n$ be the $n$th term of Fibonacci numbers. Consider the following special case of companion  matrix 
$$
C_4:=\left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
0&1&0&0\\ 
0&0&1&0\\ 
0&0&0&1\\ 
1&1&0&1
\end {array} \right)
$$

With calculation I saw, when $n$ is an integer number ($n\in \mathbf{Z}$),
 then the $(2\,n)$th power of $C_4$ matrix, based on the Fibonacci number is in the following form

$$
C_4^{2n}=
 \left( \begin {array}{cccc}  \left( f \left( n-1 \right)  \right) ^{2
}&f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n \right) &f \left( n-2 \right) f
 \left( n \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n \right) 
\\ f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n \right) &f
 \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f
 \left( n \right) & \left( f \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}
\\  \left( f \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}&f
 \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( 
n+1 \right) &f \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) 
\\ f \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f
 \left( n \right) f \left( n+2 \right) &f \left( n \right) f \left( n+
1 \right) & \left( f \left( n+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}\end {array}
 \right)
$$

In addition, the $(2\,n+1)$th power of $C_4$ matrix, by $C_4^{2n}$, is as shown

$$
C_4^{2n+1}=
 \left( \begin {array}{cccc} f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n \right) &
f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f
 \left( n \right) & \left( f \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}
\\  \left( f \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}&f
 \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( 
n+1 \right) &f \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) 
\\ f \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f
 \left( n \right) f \left( n+2 \right) &f \left( n \right) f \left( n+
1 \right) & \left( f \left( n+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}
\\  \left( f \left( n+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}&f
 \left( n+1 \right) f \left( n+2 \right) &f \left( n \right) f \left( 
n+2 \right) &f \left( n+1 \right) f \left( n+2 \right) \end {array}
 \right)
$$

My question: How to find a closed-form expression for $C_4^n$ matrix when $n$ is an integer number.?

I would appreciate for any suggestions.

**Edit(1):** One of the interesting application of these closed-forms is obtaining new formula between Fibonacci terms. For instance, with $det(C_4^{2n})=1$ and $det(C_4^{2n+1})=-1$, we find two expression about Fibonacci numbers. 
 For instance, assume that $f(n-2)=x$ and $f(n-1)=y$ then
$$
\begin{array}{ccccc}
f(n)=x+y & ,& f(n+1)=x+2\,y & , & f(n+2)=2\,x+3\, y \quad . 
\end{array}
$$

Now, by replacing the values of $f(n-i)$, $-2\leq i \leq 2$, in the equation $det(C_4^{2\,n})=1$, we obtain
the following equation based on the parameters $x$ and $y$
$$
{x}^{8}+4\,{x}^{7}y+2\,{x}^{6}{y}^{2}-8\,{x}^{5}{y}^{3}-5\,{x}^{4}{y}^
{4}+8\,{x}^{3}{y}^{5}+2\,{x}^{2}{y}^{6}-4\,x{y}^{7}+{y}^{8}=1
$$

which can be expressed by 
$$
\left( {x}^{2}+xy-{y}^{2} \right) ^{4}=1
$$

one solution of the above equation is $\left( {x}^{2}+xy-{y}^{2} \right) =1$, which is Cassini formula when $n$ is even
, interesting.

**Edit(2):**
Another application of $C_4$ matrix, is in the  *Fibonacci Coding Theory*. Suppose that, we have a message matrix called $M$
 of order $4$, as follows 
$$
M:=\left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
m_1&m_2&m_3&m_4\\ 
m_5&m_6&m_7&m_8\\ 
m_9&m_{10}&m_{11}&m_{12}\\ 
m_{13}&m_{14}&m_{15}&m_{16}
\end {array} \right)\, .
$$
where $m_i$,$1\leq i \leq 16$ are natural numbers. Now, you choose any natural numbers like $n$ and use $C_4^{2n}$ 
as an encoder matrix. The encoded matrix $E$ is obtained from the following equation

\begin{eqnarray}
E&=&M \times C_4^{2n}\quad , \\
&=& \scriptsize{
\left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
m_1&m_2&m_3&m_4\\ 
m_5&m_6&m_7&m_8\\ 
m_9&m_{10}&m_{11}&m_{12}\\ 
m_{13}&m_{14}&m_{15}&m_{16}
\end {array} \right) \, 
 \left( \begin {array}{cccc}  \left( f \left( n-1 \right)  \right) ^{2
}&f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n \right) &f \left( n-2 \right) f
 \left( n \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n \right) 
\\ f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n \right) &f
 \left( n-1 \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f
 \left( n \right) & \left( f \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}
\\  \left( f \left( n \right)  \right) ^{2}&f
 \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f \left( n-1 \right) f \left( 
n+1 \right) &f \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) 
\\ f \left( n \right) f \left( n+1 \right) &f
 \left( n \right) f \left( n+2 \right) &f \left( n \right) f \left( n+
1 \right) & \left( f \left( n+1 \right)  \right) ^{2}\end {array}
 \right)}\quad , \\
 &=& 
 \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 
e_1&e_2&e_3&e_4\\ 
e_5&e_6&e_7&e_8\\ 
e_9&e_{10}&e_{11}&e_{12}\\ 
e_{13}&e_{14}&e_{15}&e_{16}
\end {array} \right)\, .
\end{eqnarray}

By method of this [article](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.chaos.2005.12.054)
, it can be proved that there are the following relations between the entries of encoded matrix $E$:

\begin{equation}
\left\{
\begin{array}{lcccc}
\displaystyle{\frac{e_1}{e_2}=\frac{e_{5}}{e_{6}}
=\frac{e_{9}}{e_{10}}=\frac{e_{13}}{e_{14}}}\approx \frac{1}{\varphi} &,&\\
\\
\displaystyle{\frac{e_2}{e_3}=\frac{e_{6}}{e_{7}}
=\frac{e_{10}}{e_{11}}=\frac{e_{14}}{e_{15}}}\approx \varphi &,& &&(1)\\
\\
\displaystyle{\frac{e_3}{e_4}=\frac{e_{7}}{e_{8}}=
\frac{e_{11}}{e_{12}}=\frac{e_{15}}{e_{16}}}\approx \frac{1}{\varphi} &.&
\end{array}\right.
\end{equation}

where $\varphi= \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, is the [*Golden ratio*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio). Notice that, the relation between entries of 
encoded matrix $E$ is independent of message matrix $M$. For example, consider the message matrix $M$ and 
encoder matrix $C_4^{40}$,  be as follows 
$$
M=\left( \begin {array}{cccc}
 93&32&68&55\\ 
 76&23&69&92\\ 
 54&74&99&31\\ 
 32&27&29&67
\end {array} \right) \quad , \quad
C_4^{40}=
 \left( \begin {array}{cccc} 17480761&28284465&17480760&28284465\\ 
 28284465&45765226&28284465&45765225\\ 
 45765225&74049690&45765226&74049690\\
 74049690&119814915&74049690&119814916
 \end {array}
 \right)
$$
So, the encode matrix $E=M\times C_4^{40}$, is obtained in the following form
$$
E=
 \left( \begin {array}{cccc}
  9715581903&15720141722&9715581878&15720141745\\ 
 11949452536&19334620328&11949452529&19334620397\\
 9863309169&15959169509&9863309214&15959169466\\ 
 7611585662&12315804297&7611585659&12315804337
 \end {array} \right)\tag{2}
$$
we can check that the entries of the encoded matrix $(2)$,  hold in the relation $(1)$. You can find the details of 
how to detect and correct errors in the received encoded matrix $E$, at the chapter four of this [thesis](https://www.docdroid.net/EZSVY8i/fibonacci-coding.pdf.html).

Comment: Have you looked at the eigendecomposition of $C_4$? Seeing that the golden ratio is one of its eigenvalues (since it is the Frobenius companion matrix of $(x^2+1)(x^2-x-1)$), the Fibonacci numbers should certainly be expected here.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician I know what you mean but I do not know how to use this fact to solve my question. Thanks for comment.

Comment: Well, if you have $C_4=\mathbf V\mathbf D\mathbf V^{-1}$, then $C_4^n=\mathbf V\mathbf D^n\mathbf V^{-1}$... the powers of the golden ratio and its conjugate root that will show up after performing the matrix multiplication are what you can then simplify into Fibonacci numbers.

Comment: @J.M.isn'tamathematician I think with your method of comment we can not find a closed-form for $C_4^n$ by Fibonacci number. Please see this my [post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/256638/the-nth-power-of-a-matrix-by-companion-matrix). In fact, if we use Jordan canonical form., we have to work with complex eigenvalues  and if we use  Frobenius normal form, we obtain the similar companion matrix like $c_4$.

Comment: can u clarify what you are asking? you have a formula for the power of $C_4$ when the exponent is an odd integer and when it is even. doesnt that cover all integer exponents?

Comment: @abel When I want to use $C_4$ matrix in the Fibonacci coding, I need to know the closed-form of $C_4^n$ when $n$ in an integer number. In the question I used $2n$, but in general I need to find a closed-form for $C_4^n$. I do not know, why the form of $C_4^{2n}$ and $C_4^{2n+1}$ can be obtained, but obtaining the closed-form of $C_4^n$ is difficult for me.